# Font color for disabled fields in DevExpress skins is too light

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I just updated a client project from DevEx 8.x to 9.2.

Several of the forms have a number of disabled fields (for security & informational purposes), these fields are not to be edited, but are to be viewed.

However, when I did the update, these fields became close to unreadable, the font color is far too similar to the background color.

I am using the skins (Caramel (Default), Money Twins, Lilian), and overall, I like them. Can I change only the disabled font color to be darker?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the SkinEditor ?

Comment: thx, I have not, I will look at that now.

Comment: +1 @Fares, [SkinEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#SkinEditor/CustomDocument2547) is the best way!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Appearance -> ControlDisabled -> ForeColor` property in the property editor of the `layout control` to fix all disabled control text color to something that you want. You can also achieve this for each control by going to the `Properties -> AppearanceDisabled -> ForeColor` property of the control itself.